# Showing swimlane in detail view

Tags: azure-devops-server, azure-devops-server-2020

I have a custom 'work item type' in an on-premise TFS. I want to show the `System.BoardLane` field (the swimlane of the item) in the detail view of an item (when clicking the item in kanban board). I see that the field is already referenced in the `<FIELDS>` list, so I just added a `Control` tag in the `WebLayout` like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<witd:WITD application="Work item type editor" version="1.0" xmlns:witd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/workitemtracking/typedef">
  <WORKITEMTYPE name="My Custom WIT">
    <FIELDS>
      <!-- ... -->
      <FIELD name="Board Column" refname="System.BoardColumn" type="String" reportable="dimension" />
      <FIELD name="Board Column Done" refname="System.BoardColumnDone" type="Boolean" reportable="dimension" />
      <FIELD name="Board Lane" refname="System.BoardLane" type="String" reportable="dimension" />
      <!-- ... -->
    </FIELDS>
    <FORM>
      <WebLayout>
        <Page Label="Details" LayoutMode="FirstColumnWide">
          <Section>
            <Group Label="Other">
              <!-- ... -->
              <Control Label="Board Lane" Type="LabelControl" FieldName="System.BoardLane" ReadOnly="True" />
              <Control Label="Board Column" Type="LabelControl" FieldName="System.BoardColumn" ReadOnly="True" />
              <!-- ... -->
            </Group>
          </Section>
        </Page>
      </WebLayout>
    </FORM>
  </WORKITEMTYPE>
</witd:WITD>
```

But when I tried to import this modified WITD with `witadmin` it throwed an error:

```
TF237090: Does not exist or access is denied.
```

Is it possible to show board lane in an item's detail view using this way? If not, is there another way to show swimlane in detail view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, it was because the user that I used to run `witadmin` didn't have enough privilege. After switching to a more privileged user the WITD was accepted.

But `LabelControl` didn't display the content of the field so I switched to `FieldControl`:

```xml
<Control Label="Board Lane" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="System.BoardLane" />
```

No need to use attribute `ReadOnly="True"` because the control is already locked by TFS.